# Issues with Ledger Nano S Plus - not able to sign for Polkadot.js web extension

Tags: polkadot-js, ledger

Anyone know how to get in touch with the devs behind the Polkadot Ledger app?  I am having issues with the Ledger Nano S Plus when using Polkadot.js web extension?  When I try to sign, I get this error:

***Ledger error: Failed to execute 'requestDevice' on 'USB': Must be handling a user gesture to show a permission request***

I have the latest firmware and app versions.  And it is not a hardware issue since it works with LedgerLive for Polkadot, and the apps for other protocols(Eth/Solana/etc) all work.  It is a app specific issue related to version 12.9180.1, which is used for the Nano S Plus.  The version available for the regular Nano S, 12.9180.0, works fine.

I have spoken to the Ledger team, and they asked that I reach out to the app dev team.  But how?  Any help in pointing me to the right direction appreciated!!

Comment: Are you using this: https://github.com/Zondax/ledger-polkadot?

Comment: Can you please describe the steps required to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @Bruno I noticed a new version of the app available from Zondax' github.  How do I install it to my Ledger?  I only know how to install the app from LedgerLive, which currently only has the older version 10.9180.1

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi the error msg occurs in the pop-up window when I try to sign a DOT txn

Comment: Stoic the [Zondax Ledger Polkadot app](https://github.com/Zondax/ledger-polkadot) is for [development purposes only](https://github.com/Zondax/ledger-polkadot#attention). Installation instructions are [here](https://github.com/Zondax/ledger-polkadot/blob/main/docs/build.md). Please read the disclaimer: https://github.com/Zondax/ledger-polkadot#attention

Comment: @Bruno I understand.  Will wait for Ledger to approve before I install version v12.9190.0.  One question, do you know if it fixes the issue that I mentioned above.  The error when using Polkadot.js web extension to sign a txn?  Are you part of the Zondax team?  If not, how do I get in touch with them?  Thanks

Comment: I am not part of their team. If this is a polkadot{.js} error, you could try opening an issue [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/extension/issues). If it is a ledger error then maybe reach out to their support [here](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/categories/4404369571601?support=true). Oh and Zondax's contact is on [this](https://zondax.ch/contact) page.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following?

1. Open the extension in a new window (it's under the Settings menu with the gear icon)
2. Try to make a transaction from your Ledger account. This time you should get an "Unable to claim interface" error.
3. Close the extension window and try the transaction again. This time it should work.

I tried several things after reproducing this on my Nano X, so perhaps I've missed a step, but it seems it's an extension issue and what got the extension going again was opening it in a new window.

Let me know if this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Raw data signing is not supported for hardware wallets Ledger.
https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/signing